# Space-scale plots in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a multi-scale analysis and I've stumbled upon, either by personal research or recommendations (as in this [Q](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34803/hidden-markov-model-segmentation-of-different-proportions-of-binary-data)), with the concept of Space-scale analysis.

Do you know how can I plot things like this in R?:

(source: [Supplementary Fig. 15](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/fetchSingleRepresentation.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002443.s015) from [this article](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002443))
[image: scale-space representation]

Comment: It is just a heat map, so if you look up examples of [heat maps in R](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+heat+map) you should be able to find a solution. Given the density of cells in the mentioned plot, you will want to look at solutions that utilize raster graphics to plot the image as opposed to vector ones.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. What I actually want to do is the multi-scale analysis. Not the actual plot. In order to improve the question could you tell me where did my question made you misunderstand my point?

Comment: At the point where you said "Do you know how can I plot things like this in R?". It is a bit easier to answer questions that are smaller in scope, saying things like "How do I do X?" is difficult to answer besides to point to literature. It is best to show what type of research you have done so far, and if you are getting stuck at a particular point ask about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about wavelet analysis? R packages include `wavelets`, `waveslim`, `wmtsa`, or `rwt`. Not sure which have nice graphing capabilities. Package `dlpR` is from a specific field, but I have to say its `wavelet.plot` plot (use its `morlet` function to process the data) is quite nice.